# How to show login forms in browser using java framework in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tapestry

Is there a way to connect my java program used with Tapestry framework to browser? I want to do a login. I am not familiar with JSPs and Servlets but I think I'm gonna need those. Can you explain to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse and the Browser is two different programs if you do not intend to start a browser inside Eclipse.

Develop your program in eclipse if you want to do a Java program(JSP is java program written for the web)

Then host your application on a web server.

Then you can use a browser. E.g firefox, to visit your site at `http://localhost`

I recommend tomcat as a web server for JSP